# Customizing the formatting output of .sass?

Tags: css, formatting, sass, braces

```
#foo {
color:black; }
```

Is there some sort of option to prefix a newline before the trailing `}` when a `.css` file is generated from `.sass`?

I would appreciate it if someone included an example of combining `sass --watch style.scss:style.css`, which is what I'm using, along with this newline requirement.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can pass a `--style` parameter to specify what you want. I think you want the "expanded" style:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style expanded
```

See the [Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style) for different output styles.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the style to expanded: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style

Comment: If I'm not using Rails, where would I specify this? In some ~/.sass config?

Comment: As described here: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options you can pass the options into the constructor of Sass::Engine. Examples for it can also be found on that page.

Comment: Right, but it says Rack or Rails and I'm using neither.

Comment: "…or by passing an options hash to Sass::Engine#initialize." http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Engine.html#initialize-instance_method http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass "Using Sass in Ruby code is very simple. After installing the Haml gem, you can use it by running require "sass" and using Sass::Engine like so" (etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the above solution to error in the terminal. If so, you can try the below which worked for me.

sass --watch scss:css --style expanded